Resources on the history of the well-ordering principle of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$
Can you recommend a book or paper on the origin of what we nowadays call the well-ordering principle of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$?
I have several doubts regarding the provenance of this important principle. Who formulated it explicitly for the first time? Methinks that people would implicitly appeal to it in the days prior to E. Zermelo's epoch and I suppose that his contributions  to set theory had an influence in making textbook authors approach it in a more meticulous manner.
Any pointers you wish to provide on this topic are more than welcome!

I have asked this elsewhere, but I guess this question of mine does belong here...

You want it actually called "well-ordering principle" and not the former terminology "infinite descent"?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent

It would be interesting to know when it was that the change in terminology happened!

The change started happening when Cantor inspired reformulating mathematics in terms of sets and subsets, which was not the custom in arithmetic and number theory before him. The term well-ordering appeared in his 1883 paper and was developed in 1895 one, see Purisch, History of Results on Orderability and Suborderability. Still, few used this parlance until 1940s as Ngram shows. Bourbaki influence is likely

The reference to Cantor's 1883 paper is ambiguous. Cantor wrote a lengthy paper in six parts that was published over several years. Parts 4 and 5 were both published in 1883. It is in part 5 that he introduced the concept of well-ordering: Georg Cantor, "Ueber unendliche, lineare Punktmannichfaltigkeiten." Mathematische Annalen, Vol. 21, No. 4, 1883, pp. 545-591. On p. 548: "Unter einer wohlgeordneten Menge ist jede wohldefinirte Menge zu verstehen, bei welcher ..."
